# How to know the types of a getters in vue file?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuex

I have some getters.ts file, when I use that getter inside the .vue file, the type of that getters is being lost, and it says type:any. Is there a way I can know the type of a getters inside the Vue?

I tried to explicitly set the type inside the .vue file, but it seems not a very good approach.

getters.ts:

```
import { GetterTree } from "vuex";
import { RootState } from "./state";

const getters: GetterTree<RootState, RootState> = {
getTodos: (state: RootState) => state.todos,
};

export default getters;
```

state.ts:

```
import { Todo } from "types/Todo";

export interface RootState {
todos: Todo[];
}

export const state: RootState = {
todos: [] as Todo[],
};   in .vue:  computed: {
...mapGetters(["getTodos"]),
} getTodos:any
```

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: In IDE it says type: any and also loses the type interference.

Comment: Post your code from Vue file here.